# Android doesn't let me select ssl certificate from downloads while installing from storage

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, ca, burp

I am trying to install burpsuite ca certificate on my Android device(One Plus 6, Android 10) but when prompted to select my ssl certificate it does not let me select it and instead disables it as an option.
Please help[image: option disabled]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently android wants a name.pem.crt format of a certificate, converting the der certificate to pem using a tool like openssl and adding a .crt at the end solved the problem for me.